# how to export grid view excel data using save File Dialog whithout using datasource

Tags: c#, excel

I really don't know guys if U can understand my problem but I will try to make it clear as possible, I have a DataGrid view and I don't use Entity framework to fill it with data just I've displayed direct data from my database to fill it like:

```
        private void load()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UR2k_CS.Properties.Settings.StoreConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [dbo].[missingItems]", con);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(table);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["RFID"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["name"].ToString();
                 dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["model"].ToString();
                 dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["category"].ToString();
                 dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["prix"].ToString();
                 dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["ref"].ToString();

            }
```

and I want to export its data into .csv file using Save File Dialog ( to make user select save place) and I found that code on the net:

```
private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dia = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
    dia.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    dia.Filter = "Excel Worksheets (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|xls file (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if(dia.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DataTable data = null;// use the DataSource of the DataGridView here
        var excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
        var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet-name");
        // you can also use LoadFromCollection with an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(data, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);
        ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address.ToString()].AutoFitColumns();

        using(var file = File.Create(dia.FileName))
            excel.SaveAs(file);
    }
}
```

but As U see Guys I don't have data source so how to fill it with my grid view data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a datatable...

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UR2k_CS.Properties.Settings.StoreConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [dbo].[missingItems]", con);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
data.Fill(table);
```

Why dont you use just this table to export to excel?
If your datable doesnt match the columns you want to export, you still would have to manage column mapping...